# Including dates from today onwards using DateTime.Now

Tags: c#, datetime

I have this code:

```
public void SetPublisherDatesNotAvailable(string strPublisher, DateTime[]listDatesNotAvailable)
{
    if (_PublisherData.PublisherDictionary.ContainsKey(strPublisher))
    {
        Publisher pPublisher = _PublisherData.PublisherDictionary[strPublisher];
        pPublisher.Availability.DatesNotAvailable =
            new List<DateTime>(listDatesNotAvailable.Where(d => d >= DateTime.Now)); // Ignore past dates

        _PublisherData.PublisherDictionary[strPublisher] = pPublisher;
    }
}
```

But it is failing to include any entry with todays date. *It seems to be taking into account the TimeStamp too*? That would explain it. But I only want to exclude it if it was yesterdays date.

How do I fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: Go back to midnight using DateTime.Now.Date

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you mentioned in the question, Both `d` and `DateTime.Now` will take TimeStamp as well, if you wanted to exclude the TimeStamp means you have to use `d.Date` and also `DateTime.Today`(which will give you today's date without TimeStamp, and are equal to `DateTime.Now.Date` So This line `listDatesNotAvailable.Where(d => d >= DateTime.Now)` should be like this:

```
listDatesNotAvailable.Where(d => d.Date >= DateTime.Today)
```

Comment: Wow, I learned two handy things today!  DateTime.Today and DateTime.Now.Date.  Excellent!

Comment: I think this is perhaps the better way to go.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `DateTime.Now.Date` to get the value without the time component, or more precisely, with the time component set to midnight.

Comment: I learned something!  I was about to suggest constructing a new Date with the time components set to 0.  Didn't know about the Date property.

Comment: @adv12 And that is why I am a little disappointed at the down votes. Perhaps my question was too simple for them. Not to worry. Thank you very much for your help. I was stuck for ages on that one!